# Download file over HTTPS

Tags: java, xhtml

I am in a project that needs to download a file of about 10M size from the server.
And I use the direct url(https://serveraddress:port/filepath) to download it. The firefox and IE9 is ok, but IE8 not.
I searched the similar case here and it seems that something is wrong with the cookie setting.

So I added the following:

in the head of the xhtml file, but I found the response header is still as below:

Pragma  No-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache

and then I add the following:
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

in the JSP file, and use BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream to read and write the file, but it still doesn't work, it redirects to the debug.xhtml page

anyone can help?

The whole JSP file is:

```
     final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;
try {
    String fileName = request.getPathInfo();
    File fileToDownload = new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+ "installer/" + fileName);

    if(!fileToDownload.exists()){
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        return;
    }
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + fileToDownload.getName()+"\"");
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(fileToDownload.getName());

    if (contentType == null) {
        contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    response.setHeader("contentType", contentType);

    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(fileToDownload.length()));

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                fileToDownload), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response
                .getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length;
        int index = 1;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
    System.out.println("finish");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please define "not OK". What is "not OK"?

Comment: that just means not work, I can not download the file with IE8

Comment: So what *is* happening in IE8 instead?

Comment: The error message is : The requested resource () is not available.

Comment: And java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no file extension in servlet path: /install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's IE bug, try Google by keywords "IE file download https cache pragma". There are some articles about it, e.g.: http://mark.koli.ch/2009/10/internet-explorer-cant-open-file-via-https-try-removing-the-pragma-header.html , http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308

Comment: I have missed the two statements,                             out.clear(); out = pageContext.pushBody(); and now it works. thank all the guys here